# How to get average of columns grouped by a certain column?

Tags: matlab, matrix, average, mean

Consider the following matrix in MATLAB:

```
      %  x y z  V
data = [ 1 1 1  6
         1 1 2  7
         1 1 3  8
         1 2 1  6
         1 2 2  7
         1 2 3  9
         1 3 1  6
         1 3 2  4
         1 3 3  8
         2 1 1  9
         2 1 2  8]
```

How can I get the (`V` vs `z`) profile by averaging over appropriate `x` and `y`?

The result, in this case, should be:

```
B = [1, (6+6+6+9)/4); 
     2, (7+7+4+8)/4); 
     3,   (8+9+9)/3 ]
```

The average is over the all `V`s that have identical `Z`.

However, the original data contains real values:

```
0.815210000000000   1.30799000000000    -84.8230000000000   -5.90987000000000
0.815210000000000   2.42194000000000    -84.8230000000000   -0.236048000000000
0.815210000000000   3.53589000000000    -84.8230000000000   3.19780000000000
0.815210000000000   4.64984000000000    -84.8230000000000   5.48969000000000
0.815210000000000   5.76379000000000    -84.8230000000000   6.42475000000000
0.815210000000000   6.87774000000000    -84.8230000000000   5.97255000000000
0.815210000000000   7.99169000000000    -84.8230000000000   4.25794000000000
0.815210000000000   9.10564000000000    -84.8230000000000   1.49070000000000
0.815210000000000   10.2196000000000    -84.8230000000000   -2.10373000000000
```

Comment: Generally, you can do `plot(z, V)`. This will plot `V` in relation to `z` but why do you wish to average `x` and `y`?

Comment: Btw, what you have is 4D data (x, y, z and V)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to find the mean value of the groups. Prepend a column of [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) values of 3rd column to get `B`.

```
[C, ~, ic]=  unique(data(:,3));
B = [C  accumarray(ic,data(:,4),[],@mean)]
```

Be careful with the floating point values, if your values of third column are not *really* exactly the same then use [`uniquetol`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uniquetol.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using my programming knowledge with other languages:

```
A = sortrows(data, 3);
G = unique(A(:, 3));
n = size(G,1);
num = size(A,1);
B = zeros(n,2);
i =1;
oldZ=A(1,3);
sum = 0;
m =0;
for row=1:num
    z = A(row,3);
    if z ~= oldZ
        B(i,1) =oldZ;
        B(i,2)= sum/m;
        sum = 0;
        m =0;
        oldZ = z;
        i = i+1;
    end
    V = A(row,4);
    sum = sum + V;
    m = m +1;
end

B(i,1) =oldZ;
B(i,2)= sum/m;
```

B is the profile requested, which is the average in xy plane along z.